# Change user with "su" locally without password for specific user

Tags: bash, su

i have a Server with 4 users: `a, b, c, admin`
I have the plan to enable user `a` and `b` to change
to user `admin` with the command `su` (without sudo! [Because screen program]) without a password promt.

I had read something about the **`/etc/sudoers`** file but nothing which match really with my Problem.

With regards, Tim

## Solved :: Bad Idea

Don't create an Account without an password.
It can enable workarounds for users ...

Comment: Why this _"without sudo"_ requirement? [Otherwise, this ServerFault answer is perfectly valid](http://serverfault.com/questions/17814/how-can-i-allow-one-user-to-su-to-another-without-allowing-root-access).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this with `su`. It requires a password, and it should. There is likely another approach you need to take if `sudo` is not an option. Otherwise they could always `sudo -c 'su - admin'` sort of thing.

Comment: Oh yes right. Thanks. Okay i will give him a password.